# Debugs/errors in oqey gallery

Tags: plugins, gallery

When i install this plugin (oQey gallery) i report some errors like:

> 1) Notice: Undefined index: type in \wp-content\plugins\oqey-gallery\gallcore.php on line 252

On line 252:

```
if($_GET['type'] == "oqeygallery"){ include ("insert_in_post.php"); }
```

> 2) Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\wp-includes\functions.php on line 2723

on line 2723:

```
trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s was called with an argument that is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s! %3$s'), $function, $version, $message ) );
```

> 3) Notice: Undefined index: page in \wp-content\plugins\oqey-gallery\oqeygallery.php on line 346

on line 346:

```
 if(is_admin() && ($_GET['page']=='oQeysettings' || $_GET['page']=='oQeyGalleries' || $_GET['page']=='oQeySkins' || $_GET['page']=='oQeyMusic' || $_GET['page']=='oQeyTrash' || $_GET['page']=='oQeyVideo' ) ){
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Undefined Index

The first and third are the same problem:

```
if($_GET['type'] == "oqeygallery"){}
```

and

```
if(is_admin() && ($_GET['page']=='oQeysettings'...
```

Basically are:

if ( $_GET['foo'] == 'bar' )

The problme is that `$_GET['foo']` **is not set**. That is, the `$_GET` array does not have a `'foo'` key.

The solution is to wrap `$_GET['foo']` in an `isset()` conditional:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['foo'] ) && 'bar' == $_GET['foo'] )
```

### Deprecated cap

The second issue doesn't derive from the code you've quoted. Somewhere in the Plugin, a function is using an invalid cap as a parameter. You'll need to look through the plugin files, to find where the invalid cap - **likely an *integer* instead of a capability** - is being used as a parameter.

#### Edit

Found one: `gallcore.php`:

```
add_menu_page('oQey Gallery plugin', 'oQey Gallery', 8, $oqeym, 'oqey_top_page', $icon);
```

That `8`, is a user cap, but is invalid (as of several WordPress versions prior), and needs to be replaced with an actual *capability*, such as `'manage_options'`

Comment: you give me useful feedback, but i can't find the solution and solve my problem. Finally i use another plugin like lightbox, and this is enough for me. After that maybe is better to close this topic. Thanks again.